# How to make two frame animation work pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game on pygame, and I would like some advice on how to make a simple two frame animation run, and quit when a key is pressed. here is the code, and the full file is attached.

```
                screen.blit(win_screen1, [0, 0])
                pygame.display.update()
                clock.tick(13)
                screen.blit(win_screen2, [0, 0])
                clock.tick(13)
                pygame.display.update()
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        playing = True
                        win = False
                        reset()
```

I would have thought this would make the animation run at 13 FPS, and stop when a key is pressed, but it plays really inconsistently and slowly, and pressing a key does nothing. I saw in another post someone saying they used `pygame.time.Clock()`, but I'm not really sure how it works, and many methods only cap the framerate, not set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the animated item up into an object, that way it can maintain its own internal timings, and draw the correct bitmap.  I would use a PyGame sprite for this, but you can make your own too.

The idea is to use the internal PyGame clock to record when the current frame is first displayed.  Then in some kind of every-frame update function, determine if enough milliseconds have elapsed to warrant moving to the next frame.  You desire 13 FPS, so that's 1000/13 -> every 77 milliseconds.

That gives us a rough function:

```
drawAnimation()
    What is the time now?
    Has 77 milliseconds elapsed since the last update?
       Advance to the next image in the list
    Draw the image
```

There's a bit of house-keeping around looping the frames, and maintaining the timestamp, but it's not much more complex than the above pseudocode.  The trick is keeping all that contained within a single data object which can be passed around.  This keeps the other frame-timings (like the window FPS) nicely separate.  As I said, a PyGame Sprite is ideal for holding all this data, but even a simple python list would work in a pinch.

[image: example_image]

Animation From: https://rvros.itch.io/animated-pixel-hero (Used under permissive licence).  Scaled 200%

Here's a Sprite based implementation. Please add a comment if you have queries.

```
class MultiFrameSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__( self, fps, list_of_frames ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )

        # Load all the specified animation frames
        self.frames = []
        for filename in list_of_frames:
            self.frames.append( pygame.image.load( filename ).convert_alpha() )

        # Start the animation at the first frame
        self.image = self.frames[0]
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()

        # Frame handling - index frame, and time used
        self.millisec_rate = 1000 // fps   # inter-frame delay in milliseconds
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.last_frame_at = 0

        # we need to be somewhere on-screen
        self.rect.center = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 )

    def update(self):
        # Compare the time of the last frame to time-now
        # and determine if it's time to show the next frame
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.last_frame_at + self.millisec_rate ):
            # new frame needed!
            self.last_frame_at = time_now
            # Advance to the next frame
            self.current_frame += 1
            if ( self.current_frame == len( self.frames ) ):
                self.current_frame = 0                           # wrap frame loop index
            # Set the new image
            self.image = self.frames[ self.current_frame ]
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
            # TODO: handle any x/y changes needed by differing animation sizes
```

Note that we never make just a 2, or 3, or 10 frame animation.  It's just a list of *N* images.  When we get to the end of the list (however long it is), it just goes back to the start.  This way the same code can be used for a `2` or `22` frame animation.

Reference Code:

```
import pygame
import random

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 300
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 300
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

DARK_BLUE = (   3,   5,  54)

class MultiFrameSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__( self, fps, list_of_frames ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )

        # Load all the specified animation rames
        self.frames = []
        for filename in list_of_frames:
            self.frames.append( pygame.image.load( filename ).convert_alpha() )

        # Start the animation at the first frame
        self.image = self.frames[0]
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()

        # Frame handling
        self.millisec_rate = 1000 // fps   # inter-frame delay in milliseconds
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.last_frame_at = 0

        # we need to be somewhere on-screen
        self.rect.center = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 )

    def update(self):
        # Compare the time of the last frame to time-now
        # and determine if it's time to show the next frame
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.last_frame_at + self.millisec_rate ):
            # new frame needed!
            self.last_frame_at = time_now
            # preserve the centroid in case the frames are differing sizes
            x,y = self.rect.center
            # Advance to the next frame
            self.current_frame += 1
            if ( self.current_frame == len( self.frames ) ):
                self.current_frame = 0                           # wrap frame loop index
            # Set the new image
            self.image = self.frames[ self.current_frame ]
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (x,y)                             # restore the centroid co-ordinate


### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption( "Multi-Frame Sprite" )


### Create Sprites
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
adventurer  = MultiFrameSprite( 5, [ 'adventurer-idle-00.png', 
                                     'adventurer-idle-01.png', 
                                     'adventurer-idle-02.png', 
                                     'adventurer-idle-03.png' ] )
all_sprites.add( adventurer )


### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    all_sprites.update()
    window.fill( DARK_BLUE )
    all_sprites.draw( window )       # Paint ALL the sprites
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)


pygame.quit()
```

Note: I use 5 FPS in the code above, since it was a reasonable fit for the animation.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It has been very helpful.